# JqueryFlot inconsistent issue IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, flot, jquery-hover

i am using Jquery Flot chart library and i was able to create a Time Line Chart but i have a problem with IE 8.

Basically  the hover event works only for some points.
Using instead Google Chrome i don't face this issue.

Here the tooltip part:

```
var previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

$.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
    $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {         

            if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                previousLabel = item.series.label;
                $("#tooltip").remove();

                var x = item.datapoint[0];
                var y = item.datapoint[1];                

                var color = item.series.color;
               // var month = new Date(x).getMonth();

                    showTooltip(item.pageX,
                            item.pageY,
                            color,
                            "<strong>" +  y + "</strong>");

            }
        } else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
};

function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 40,
        left: x - 120,
        border: '2px solid ' + color,
        padding: '3px',
        'font-size': '9px',
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        opacity: 0.9
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}
```

Could you please help me to find the root cause and a possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: And which version of Flot?  Is there anything special about the points?  Are they all on a particular series?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I add:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
```

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same issue:

https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1053

The following is the workaround which needs to be applied to the main jquery.flot.js file (although it's not targetted against the latest version it should hopefully point you in the right derection)

> In the bind events method (line
>   1291) add
>
> $(".flot-base").mousemove(onMouseMove);
>
> In the shutdown method on line
>   1314 add
>
> $(".flot-base").unbind("mousemove", onMouseMove);